# Get Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'JS$' is undefined Error While Using magnific-popup

Tags: popup, magnific-popup

I am using magicnific popup from this website: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

This is my code:

```
   <head>
  <link href="Scripts/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script>
JS$(document).ready(function() {
$('.popup-with-form').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline',
    preloader: false,
    focus: '#name',

    // When elemened is focused, some mobile browsers in some cases zoom in
    // It looks not nice, so we disable it:
    callbacks: {
        beforeOpen: function() {
            if($(window).width() < 700) {
                this.st.focus = false;
            } else {
                this.st.focus = '#name';
            }
        }
    }
});
   });
    </script>
  </head>
```

This is my body:

```
  <body>
    HTML<!-- link that opens popup -->
<a class="popup-with-form" href="#test-form">Open form</a>

 <!-- form itself -->
  <form id="test-form" class="mfp-hide white-popup-block">
<h1>Form</h1>
<fieldset style="border: 0px currentColor;">

    <ol>
        <li>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text"     placeholder="Name" required="">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" required="">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Eg. +447500000000" required="">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="textarea">Textarea</label><br>
            <textarea id="textarea">Try to resize me to see how popup CSS-based resizing works.</textarea>
        </li>
    </ol>
</fieldset>
  </form>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


 <script src="Scripts/jquery.magnific-popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


  </body>
```

I have a Script Folder under my project root that Contains these files:

```
jquery-1.11.0.min.js
jquery.magnific-popup.js
jquery.magnific-popup.min.js
magnific-popup.css
```

When I Run the Project I am getting this error:

```
 Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'JS$' is undefined
```

Do you know where I had mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Remove "JS" from

```
JS$(document).ready(function() {
```

It should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

when you copied it from Magnific web page, your selection highlight accidentally grabbed "JS" from the top right corner.